# RaphaelJs: Circle doesn't show proper value

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have a problem with Raphael library.
I'm trying to load image inside circle in four steps:

```
1 step = 25% of circle  
2 step = 50% of circle  
3 step = 75% of circle  
4 step = 100% of circle
```

If I start from step 2(50%) everything works fine, but if I start from 25% image doesn't show proper. It looks like image is out of circle. Here is live example, I hope it will explain what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/H4CJF/1/

```
var amount = 25;

var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 350, 350);
archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value, 
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
        ];
    } else {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
        ];
    }
    return {
        path: path
    };
};


var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
    "fill": "url(http://i.imgur.com/YR5gCBV.png)",
    arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 50]
}).rotate(180);



function next_step() {;
    amount = amount + 25;
    my_arc.attr({
        arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 50]
    })
};

var el = document.getElementById("more"); 
     el.addEventListener("click", next_step, false);
```

Image is 100x100, radius 50px. I would to like fill circle with image, without white space or reapeted background.
Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:** Here is how does look my image:

[image]

If I set amount to 25 and then I click Next Step, circle looks like this:
[image]
while it should be half of orginal image (red on top, yellow on bottom).
I think it something with position from where is start draw circle, but I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

OK it was just a strange little bug! The incrementing of the amount was causing the value to exceed 100 - therefore the code that checks to see if the value is at the total `amount == total` only got ran the first time:

```
Start:   25
Click 1: 50
Click 2: 75
Click 3: 100   <--only time it got ran at full
Click 4: 125
```

To avoid this, just add in a mod line to reduce the number down and all is fixed:

```
function next_step() {
    amount = amount % 100;   <--amount will never exceed 100 now
    amount = amount + 25;
    my_arc.attr({
        arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 50]
    })
};
```

The `mod` line needs to be **above** the increment line, or it will turn a full value of 100 into a 0, and we have the same problem.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it clearly. I have updated my post. Thanks for help!